# Comparing the dataframe contents and changing the column color if condition is not met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as shown below. I need to compare `min` with spec_min and 'max' with spec_max.
If max>Spec_max then the color of the `max` cell should be read and if min<Spec_min then that also needs to be red. May I know how to do this?

```
                 min    max  SPEC_MIN SPEC_MAX
V_PTAT3V3[V]    1.124   1.14    1.095   1.2
```

Comment: So in example data are not color? if min=1 and max=5 then are red both columns `min, max` ?

Comment: In example data is not in color.Because min and max lies between SPEC_MIN and SPEC_MAX.If min and max are outside SPEC_MAX and SPEC_MIN then the color of min and max needs to be changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may. Here is an example. Assuming your dataframe looks somewhat like this

```
         min       max  spec_min  spec_max
0   1.298092  0.857875       1.0       1.2
1   1.814168  1.032747       0.8       1.0
2   1.396925  1.092014       1.0       1.2
3   1.616848  1.279176       0.8       1.0
4   1.956991  1.200024       1.0       1.2
5   1.649614  1.203371       1.0       1.2
6   1.195811  0.432663       1.2       1.4
7   1.313263  0.795951       1.2       1.4
8   1.157487  1.235014       1.0       1.2
9   1.546830  1.094696       1.2       1.4
10  1.135896  0.792172       0.8       1.0
11  1.561299  0.763911       1.2       1.4
12  1.324006  0.956222       1.0       1.2
13  1.283233  0.585565       1.0       1.2
14  1.179644  0.983332       1.2       1.4
15  1.696883  1.199471       1.2       1.4
16  1.130002  0.947254       0.8       1.0
17  1.249352  0.865932       1.2       1.4
18  1.365273  0.721204       1.0       1.2
19  1.155129  0.722179       1.2       1.4
20  1.315393  0.590603       0.8       1.0
```

```
def highlight_under_spec_min(s, props=''):
    return np.where(s < df['spec_min'], props, '')

def highlight_under_spec_max(s, props=''):
    return np.where(s > df['spec_max'], props, '')

df.style.apply(highlight_under_spec_min, props='color:white;background-color:red', subset=['min'], axis=0)\
    .apply(highlight_under_spec_max, props='color:white;background-color:red', subset=['max'], axis=0)
```

gives you

[image]

If this is not what you want I suggest you give an example with cells you want and don't want colored.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try something like this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'min': 1.124, 'max': 1.14, 'SPEC_MIN': 1.095, 'SPEC_MAX': 1.2}])

def style_cells(dataframe):
    """This function is to be used with the Panda's apply method to 
    color the cells based on different conditions."""
    # Preparing styles.
    conditional_style = 'background-color: red'
    default_style = '' 
    # Comparing values and creating masks.
    mask = dataframe['min'] < dataframe['SPEC_MIN']
    # Creating a style DataFrame with same indices and columns as in the original DataFrame. 
    df =  pd.DataFrame(default_style, index=dataframe.index, columns=dataframe.columns)
    # Modifying cell colors.
    df.loc[mask, 'min'] = conditional_style
    # The same procedure for max values.
    mask = dataframe['max'] > dataframe['SPEC_MAX']
    df.loc[mask, 'max'] = conditional_style
    return df

df.style.apply(style_cells, axis=None)
```